# seting scaleX property of movieclip also scaleY as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have movieClip and I set scaleX property to 2. But My movieClip height is also scaled.

```
trace("height " + mc.height);
trace("width " + mc.width);

mc.scaleX = 2;

trace("height " + mc.height);
trace("width " + mc.width);
```

output is:

```
10
10

10
20
```

But i see on screen that ma movieClip height is also scaled. Why is this happening and how I prevent this ? What should I do if i want only scale width but not height.

Comment: Try doing mc.scaleY = 0.5 after mc.scaleX. Not sure if it will work but maybe worth a try

Comment: when I do this, my width is scaled automaticly.

Comment: Is this a plain MovieClip, or is there code associated with it? Is there code somewhere else in the project that could changing the size?

Comment: it is movieclip i am loading from external swf. I am just adding movieclip to stage.

Comment: Is there code in the external SWF that could be changing the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer how to predict this behaviour. Movieclip was loaded from extarnal swf, which was made in flash profesional.

I just had to set up in movieclip properties: enabled guides for 9 slice scaling.

You get to this menu by right click on movie clip in Library panel and than properties.